# IE 11 Developer Tool - Memory Profiler Snapshot disappeared after page refresh or navigating to another page

Tags: internet-explorer, ie11-developer-tools

I would like to find memory leak using IE 11 Developer tool. In that, I could able to take memory profiler snapshot for one page. But when i am navigating to another page, previous snapshot not showing. So, i couldn't able to do comparison between current and last page.

BUt in chrome, snapshots not removed while navigating and also allowing us to save it. Is there any solution to do comparison between pages?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what version of IE 11 you have. Try the Dev Channel version at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43359 and it should let you save memory snapshots. So you can take a snapshot before you navigate, then take one after you navigate and you can then import them into the tool and compare.

Comment: With the latest August Update, you no longer have to download the Dev Channel for this feature. You should now be able to save/load memory snapshots from with the dev tools in IE11.

For more information on what else is new, see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/08/14/announcing-new-f12-dev-tools-features-in-august-update.aspx

Comment: Save and import, but no option to actually compare snapshots from different sessions.